# Getting a "Error: Cannot find module" using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting a 'Error: Cannot find module' when running my script. 
Using require('path');

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []

```
const path = require('path');

//Base file name
console.log("File Name:");

console.log("File Name: " + __filename);
console.log(path.basename(__filename));

 // //Base directory name
// console.log(__dirname);
console.log(path.dirname(__filename));

//File extension
console.log(path.extname(__filename));

//Create Path Object
console.log(path.parse(__filename).base);

//Concatenate Paths
//../test/hello.html
console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'test','hello.html'));
```

Comment: '/Users/alexbrito/Documents/VisualStudioCode/NodeCrashCourse/path_demo.js' is the path. When really 'path_demo.js' is located in a subdirectory in NodeCrashCourse. '/Users/alexbrito/Documents/VisualStudioCode/NodeCrashCourse/reference/path_demo.js '. I ended up moving 'path_demo.js' into the parent directory. Which solved it. Makes sense because the error is telling me it can find a module that located in the /NodeCrashCourse/.. directory. My question now is. Why wasn't it finding when it was in a subdirectory in NodeCrashCourse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is in a different directory that specified.

Comment: How I can run a file thats located in a subdirectory? @Peter

Comment: You can do ./dirName to reference down a directory

Comment: Ahhhh okay. Thank you @Peter